# Markdown heading with a bullet

Tags: markdown, bullet

I am aware this might be a weird requirement that does not fit into the semantics of markdown, but is it possible to have a bulleted heading?

I.e. is there a way to combine `# Key point` with `- Key point` into something like `# - Key point`? Obviously, this does not render the heading with a bullet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Unicode symbol instead of relying on Markdown to process the bullet. [U+2022 BULLET is probably your best bet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(typography)#In_Unicode):

```
# • Key point
```

Here it is rendered on Stack Overflow:

## • Key point

Comment: in fact `&bull;` is also valid markdown and can save extra searching for the literal unicode character, but it is a smaller size bullet than `&#9679;`